# what do the parentheses accomplish around the assignment

Tags: javascript, angularjs

More of a JavaScript question. But I ran into it while learning about Angular!

Why does the assignment to $scope.clock have curly braces? I took them out, it certainly doesn't produce a correct outcome without them! What is the technique called in Javascript?

```js
function MyController($scope) {
   $scope.clock = {
      now: new Date()
   };
   var updateClock = function() {
      $scope.clock.now = new Date();
   };
   setInterval(function() {
      $scope.$apply(updateClock);
      }, 1000);
   updateClock();
};
```

Comment: To which parentheses are you referring, exactly?

Comment: $scope.clock = {now: new Date()};

Comment: Curly braces is what I call 'em. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Amazing that people start learning Angular even without any basic javascript background. Anyway, good luck! :)

Comment: Eh, might as well jump in with both feet.

Comment: Well, I'm learning Javascript as I read throughout a Javascript book. Is that illegal ;)

Answer (score 4):

In this case, `$scope.clock` is being assigned to a Javascript object. More correctly, this is known as an 'object literal' notation.

Comment: The other way around. The object is assigned to the `@scope.clock` property.

Comment: Actually it is being assigned an object, not assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

the curly brackets define the clock variable as an object. What this means if you can assign variables on this object, like the now variable. so that you can do this. angular aside.

```
var clock = {
  now: new Date()
};
alert(click.now);
```

This will show an alert box with the result of new Date(). You can add variables to object in other ways as well.

```
var clock = {};
clock.now = new Date();
```

This is the same thing as above.

With angular all you are doings is assigning the clock variable on the $scope. and then giving the newly assigned clock variable a now variable. Which would look like this.

```
var iAmAnObject = {};
iAmAnObject.clock = {
    now: new Date()
};
```